# d3js: How does the "magic" work with fill on hover for a barchart plot?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

There are multiple versions of the D3 JS v3 barchart plot around that have the feature of changing the bar color when the mouse hovers over it. I have a minimal working barchart and wanted to add it but it doesn't change the bar fill color upon hovering over it.

Looking at [this barchart example](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) that is built on top of v3 I only see that the needed addendum is this css snippet:

```
.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered;
}
```

therefore I added this but I can't see the change of fill color on hovering ... where else does the magic come from?

**UPDATE:** This is my D3 JS barchart plot generating code:

```
// delete old
d3.select("#" + divId).select("svg").remove();

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var max = d3.max(values);
var min = d3.min(values);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range([0, width]);

// generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(10))
    (values);

var yMax = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.length });
var yMin = d3.min(data, function(d){ return d.length });
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([yMin, yMax])
    .range([d3.rgb(color).brighter(), d3.rgb(color).darker()]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("#" + divId)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.y) });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("x", (x(data[0].dx) - x(0)) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .classed("label", true)
    .text($scope.histogramData.spec[$scope.histogramData.selected]);
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: From nowhere else.This line of code you included should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example the class `bar` is assigned to the rectangles.

In your code, however, the class is assigned to `<g>` tags, which will not trigger on hover.

If you change the CSS to the following, it should work:

```
.bar rect:hover {
  fill: orangered;
}
```